# Como adicionar o símbolo de real brasileiro (R$) no LaTex?

Tags: latex

Gostaria de saber como inserir o símbolo de `R$` no LaTex utilizando o Overleaf? É algum pacote que tenho que inserir?

Answer (score 3):

Para **gerar o símbolo monetário brasileiro** não é necessário nenhum pacote, apenas utiliza-se o `\` da seguinte forma sem que ocorra nenhum erro:

Forma no LaTex:

```
R\$ 10,00 = R$ 10,00
```